# Matching array pattern algorithm

Tags: java, arrays

Given 2 arrays **a = [b,b,c]** and **array e = [o,o,p]**, they match each other but these wouldn't match array like **[x,y,y]** or **[a,b,c]**. I was asked to write an (possibly recursive) algorithm in Java as a part of a job test.

Answer (score 5):

You can look into this fragment of code:-

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MatchPatterns {

    public static void main(String ani[]) {
        char[] a= {'b','b','c'};
        char[] b= {'o','o','p'};
        
        System.out.println(doTheyMatch(a, b));
    }

    private static boolean doTheyMatch(char[] a, char[] b) {
        if(a.length != b.length) {
            return false;
        }
        
        int aInteger[] = new int[a.length];
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        int charRepresentator = 0;
        for(int i =0 ;i <a.length; i++) {
            if(map.containsKey(a[i])){
                aInteger[i] = map.get(a[i]).intValue();
            }else {
                map.put(a[i], charRepresentator);
                aInteger[i] =  charRepresentator;
                charRepresentator++;
            }
            
        }
        
        
        int bInteger[] = new int[b.length];
        map = new HashMap<>();
        
        charRepresentator = 0;
        for(int i =0 ;i <b.length; i++) {
            if(map.containsKey(b[i])){
                bInteger[i] = map.get(b[i]).intValue();
            }else {
                map.put(b[i], charRepresentator);
                bInteger[i] =  charRepresentator;
                charRepresentator++;
            }
            
        }
        
        for(int i =0 ;i < aInteger.length; i++) {
            if(aInteger[i] != bInteger[i]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you were right so now instead of using HashSet, now I use the stack. So whenever a similar character comes in I pop the character else I push the character. Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: Yeah!. corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Map` to remember the mappings seen so far:

```java
private static boolean isSamePattern(char[] a, char[] b) {
    if (a.length != b.length)
        return false;
    Map<Character, Character> mapping = new HashMap<>();
    Set<Character> mapped = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        Character expected = mapping.get(a[i]);
        if (expected == null) {
            if (! mapped.add(b[i]))
                return false; // b value already mapped from different a value
            mapping.put(a[i], b[i]);
        } else if (b[i] != expected) {
            return false; // a value not mapped to same b value
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(isSamePattern("bbc".toCharArray(), "oop".toCharArray()));
System.out.println(isSamePattern("bbc".toCharArray(), "xyy".toCharArray()));
System.out.println(isSamePattern("bbcc".toCharArray(), "xxyx".toCharArray()));
System.out.println(isSamePattern("abc".toCharArray(), "efe".toCharArray()));
```

*Output*

```
true
false
false
false
```

Comment: abc and efe would return true. Which I don't think is intended.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm could go like this. We would use hash map data structure.

```
 step1: keep a map to store the mapping of values from array a to e(let map1) and mapping from e to a (let map2)
 step2: Traverse through array a and get one character at a time. Let it be ch1.
 step3: For the same character get a character from array e. Let it be ch2.
 step4: if(ch1 already in map1)
       step4.a: if ch1 = it's map1 mapped character. continue to step2
       step4.b: if ch1 != it's mapped charecter. goto step7
 step5: if(ch1 not in map1)
       step5.a: if ch2 already in map2
             step5.a.a: Goto 7
       step5.b: if ch2 has no mapping in map2: add this 2 mappings in map1 and map 2 and goto step2
step6: Traverse completed without error mapping exists.
step7: Error occurred: break
```

Time: Time to traverse string*Finding in maps

Space: The 2 maps that we create.

Edit: Added the c++ code for this:

```
bool check(string a, string b) {
if(a.size()!=b.size())
    return false;
map<char,char>hashA;
map<char,char>hashB;

for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){
    if(hashA.find(a[i])==hashA.end()){
        if(hashB.find(b[i])==hashB.end()){
            hashA[a[i]]=b[i];
            hashB[b[i]]=a[i];
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        if(b[i]!=hashA[a[i]]){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;}
```

Comment: Why two maps? One map is enough.

Comment: 2nd map would check if the character in 2nd array has already been matched or not. Like for patterns like "abc" and "efe".

Comment: Ahh, right, though it can be just a `Set`, no need for `Map`

Answer (score 0):

Using the stuff I have learnt so far I attempted this. It might not be as efficient as the previous answers, but still I wanted to try.

What I've done is allow the user to enter 2 different patterns. They are then stored in arrays and is compared. If the patterns are not of the same length, obviously, they don't match. But if they are of the same length, I compare each character with the next. A 1 is used to represent a match in the characters and a 0 if it's not. This process is repeated all the way till the character before the last.

The pattern of 1s and 0s are stored in two strings. Finally, I compare the two strings and if they are equal, it means that the entered patterns match.

```
import java.util.* ;

public class MatchPatterns
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in) ;
       String entry ;

       System.out.print("Enter a pattern : ") ;
       entry = scan.next() ;
       entry = entry + scan.nextLine() ;

       char a[] = new char[entry.length()] ;

       for(int index = 0 ; index < entry.length() ; index++)
       {
           a[index] = entry.charAt(index) ;
       }


       System.out.print("Enter another pattern : ");
       entry = scan.next() ;
       entry = entry + scan.nextLine() ;

       char b[] = new char[entry.length()] ;

       for(int index = 0 ; index < entry.length() ; index++)
       {
           b[index] = entry.charAt(index) ;
       }

       if(isAMatch(a, b) == true)
           System.out.println("it's a match!") ;
       else
           System.out.println("not a match") ;
    }
    
    private static Boolean isAMatch(char a[], char b[])
    {
        boolean match = false ;
        String pattern1 = "" ;
        String pattern2 = "" ;

        if(a.length == b.length)
        {
            for(int counter = 0 ; counter < a.length-1 ; counter++)
            {
                if(a[counter] == a[counter+1])
                    pattern1 = pattern1 + "1" ;
                else                
                    pattern1 = pattern1 + "0" ;
            }           

            for(int counter = 0 ; counter < b.length-1 ; counter++)
            {
                if(b[counter] == b[counter+1])
                   pattern2 = pattern2 + "1" ;
                else                
                   pattern2 = pattern2 + "0" ;
            }

            if(pattern1.equals(pattern2))
               match = true ;
        }

        return match ;
   }
}
```